# Jenkins Console Output don't show all the build info

Tags: jenkins

When I build a code in command line, the command show an error and stop the build, but when i do the same in jenkins, the jenkins doesn't show the error and and show that  the code was builded with sucessful.

Looking at the same point of the code that the error happened, the command line give me this following information:

> "libs\init\InitData.c", line 92: error #65: expected a ";"
>           ++src
>             ^
>   Error: build failed

and in Jenkins there is a blank space.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Jenkins considers command a failure if the exit code is different than 0. I'm guessing that despite error in your script the exit value is still 0.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to make another error for test, but do you know how can i set jenkins for considers this code, like i wrote above, a build error?